# How do I save a UIImageView with subviews to Camera roll?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have an app that takes a picture from the camera and puts it in a UIImageView. After you can add small "clipart" pictures to it, which is addded as subviews to the UIImageView (tempImageView in my code).

But when I try to save the image by tempImageView.image to the camera the image gets much bigger and also the subviews added to it doesn't come along. Any idea how to save the UIImageView with my subviews to the camera roll?

Here is how I save the image:

```
@IBAction func saveImageButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(tempImageView.image!, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
}

func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>) {
    if error == nil {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And here is how I add pictures to my tempImageView:

```
@IBAction func berlockButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let imageName = "berlock.png"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 60, height: 100)

    tempImageView.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to draw your image and the image view's subviews in an image context and "take a picture" of that context. I haven't tested this code, but this will get you started:

```
// Create the image context to draw in
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

// Get that context
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

// Draw the image view in the context
imageView.layer.renderInContext(context!)

// You may or may not need to repeat the above with the imageView's subviews  
// Then you grab the "screenshot" of the context
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

// Be sure to end the context
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

// Finally, save the image
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick, also I did not need to repeat for my tempImageViews subviews if anyone wonders.

Answer (score 1):

You should render image something like,

```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, imageView.opaque, 0.0)

    imageView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

     let resultImageToStore = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

You can give your desired size instead of `imageView.bounds.size`. `imageView.bounds.size` keep your imageview's size.

Consider `imageView` as your imageView which have another subviews.

`resultImageToStore` is the final image which you should store.

Comment: Thank you, this probably works as well from what I can see but I used keithbhunter's solution which were a little bit more explainatory.